# Add dimensions to an array from a list

Tags: python, arrays

The structure of my array 'cama' is the following:

```
shape(cama)
>>>(365, 720, 1440)
```

And the shape of my 'lon_list' is the following:

```
shape(lon_list)
>>>(1440,)
```

What I want is to add or append lon_list to cama. So that I end up with an array with the following dimensions:

```
shape(new_cama)
>>>(365, 720, 1440, 1440)
```

I've tried:

```
new_cama = np.concatenate((cama, lon_list))
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You want to append an array with 1440 elements to an array with 365*720*1440=378432000 elements, and you expect to get 365*720*1440*1440=544942080000 elements? That's not how arrays or appending work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dimensions are *multiplicative*. This means if you have:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

You have a `(2 x 3)` array of 6 elements. If you want to add another dimension, say `b=[10, 20, 30, 40]`, you will end up with an array of `(2 x 3 x 4) = 24` elements, so you need to provide a way to complete these missing `(24 - 4 - 6) = 14` elements. You cannot 'append' a dimension: increasing the dimension means appending `newdimiension - 1` elements in *all* dimensions.

So what can we do with shapes like this ? Well, you can broadcast your arrays to match the corresponding dimension and combine them in some way:

```
In[52]: a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
In[53]: b = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40])
In[54]: a
Out[54]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
In[55]: b
Out[55]: array([10, 20, 30, 40])
In[56]: c = a[:, :, None] * b[None, None, :]
In[57]: c
Out[57]: 
array([[[ 10,  20,  30,  40],
        [ 20,  40,  60,  80],
        [ 30,  60,  90, 120]],

       [[ 40,  80, 120, 160],
        [ 50, 100, 150, 200],
        [ 60, 120, 180, 240]]])
In[58]: c.shape
Out[58]: (2L, 3L, 4L)
```

Here I have multiplied them, but it is of course possible to use any other combination: the key thing to understand is that:

- You can only apply operations to arrays of *similar shapes*
- You can 'emulate' bigger shapes via broadcasting.

This way, we can combine a `(2, 3)` and a `(4,)` arrays by 'viewing' them both as `(2, 3, 4)` arrays and combining them in some way. But you have to have them make sense as arrays of similar shapes.

Alternatively, you can concatenate arrays, if all their dimensions but one differ. Say you have a `(2, 3, 4, 5)` array and a `(2, 3, 7, 5)` array: then it makes sense to concatenate them in a `(2, 3, 4+7, 5)` array. You can again do that by 'emulating' shapes (basically by repeating the pattern along any missing dimension) but from your question, it's unclear this is what you're trying to achieve...